# Publish Platform Event using .Net APIs without human intervention

Tags: rest-api, integration, platform-event, external-app

I have created a `platform event trigger` in salesforce and on the other hand I have a .Net APIs (with no UI) now. I want to publish a platform event from `.Net` API to `Salesforce`. Option that I explored is to use the [Salesforce Rest APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm) to publish the payload pertaining to that `Platform Event`.

Now the issue is my .Net APIs do not have the UI wherein it can authenticate the Salesforce user by entering the username and password hence I could not use the `oAuth` mechanism. I can't even authenticate the .Net API using the `username` and `password` of salesforce as client will not be going to share it.

Is there any other way to call `Salesforce Res APIs` to publish an event in Salesforce without using human intervention to add a username and a password.

Comment: There are oAuth flows that do not require any user interaction nor do they require a username or password. Salesforce docs cover this.

Comment: Can you share that link

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5 look for server-to-server

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, there has to be a way for you to log in. Is seems unlikely that you will be able to achieve a reliable integration WITHOUT logging in. I guess you will need to talk to your client or make a call to middleware which has the credentials. Either way, you will need the credentials or atleast a way to authenticate.

---

This is very well documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm) using the REST API. You will need a token generated via username/password and security token `server to server` flow without any user intervention, you can have a look at it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) and for this, you will need a salesforce user with a Salesforce license.

Once you get the token, you will need to make a POST call to

`<instance-url>/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Event_Name__e/` <= Your event name.

with the body as:

```
{
   "Field_1__c" : "XZO-5",
   "Field_2__c" : "XZO-5"
}
```

The `instance url` is returned in the authorization call.

Comment: I too had mentioned in my question that  `I can't even authenticate the .Net API using the username and password of salesforce as client will not be going to share it`

Comment: Updated my answer